# Cannot figure out how to get RANKX to work

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have been struggling with this for the past two days. I am trying to use Power BI to create a simple report to show the top 10 occurrences of something.

I have a table called Requests that has the following:

```
Id    Code
1     00001
2     00001
3     00500
4     00001
5     00500
6     00730
...
```

I am trying to count every occurrence of Code and display the top 10:

```
Code    Count    Rank
00001   3        1     
00500   2        2
00730   1        3
```

I created a measure called Count:

```
Count = COUNTROWS(Requests)
```

I tried to create a measure for rank in the following ways:

```
Rank = RANKX(ALL(Requests), [Count])
Rank = RANKX(Requests, [Count])
```

Everything is getting the same value of 1:

```
Code    Count    Rank
00001   3        1
00500   2        1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in [Top N Filter](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-desktop-october-feature-summary/#topN) if you don't want too much hassle. Just set a Top N Filter for the `Code` column showing top 10 by value of `Count`:

[image: result]

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. I wanted the top 10 results and I read somewhere else that I had to use RANKX to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason you get all 1's is that the measure you created will just give you the total number of rows in your table each time it's used, and then you basically try to rank the same number against itself over and over, for each row.

You can get what you want by using `TOPN` and then `RANKX`. To do that, create a new table and enter this code to get the top 10 Codes from the Requests table, based on Id counts:

```
TOP10 = TOPN(10,GROUPBY(Requests,Requests[Code],"Count",countx(CURRENTGROUP(),Requests[Id])))
```

Then add a new column with this code to do the ranking:

```
Rank = RANKX(TOP10,TOP10[Count])
```

You'll get this result from your first 6 rows that you showed above:

[image]

Comment: This would make it very difficult to change it to Top X since the table is coded for 10. Is there no way without creating another table?

Comment: Maybe this would help then: Start with your Requests table, then add a column with this code: `Rank = rankx(Requests,calculate(countx(Requests,Requests[Code]),filter(Requests,Requests[Code]=earlier(Requests[Code]))),,DESC,Dense)`. It should rank order every row from 1 through n.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using VALUES and a variable for a calculated table in Power BI Desktop:

```
Top 10 Codes =
VAR MyTable =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        VALUES ( Requests[Code] ),
        "Occurences", COUNTROWS ( RELATEDTABLE ( Requests ) )
    )
RETURN
    TOPN (
        10,
        ADDCOLUMNS ( MyTable, "Rank", RANKX ( MyTable, [Occurences] ) ),
        [Rank], ASC
    )
```